# htaccess page redirection except my ip

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make a .htaccess redirection that can do the following things:

- Redirect page A to page B;
- Redirect all traffic except my IP.

Can you pls help me?

Comment: Problem solved: RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !12\.34\.56\.78$ (my ip)
RewriteRule pageA pageB  [R=301]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

## Where to Redirect

ErrorDocument 403 [*Where to Redirect to*]
order deny,allow

---

## Block Everyone

deny from all

---

## Except for...

allow from [*YourIPGoesHere*]

---

## Full Code Example:

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.google.com/
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 173.194.41.134
```

---

## Edit:

You can also try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^173\.194\.41\.134
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/somethingHere\.html$
RewriteRule .* /somethingHere.html [R=302,L]
```

---

Comment: I don't like a lot the idea to use an error as redirect, search engines won't appreciate that very much

Comment: Edited - This should work as well, without irritating any search engines.

Comment: The code is like this:

RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !12\.34\.56\.78$ (my ip) 
RewriteRule pageA pageB [R=301]

The question is...how can I add another redirect? If I do it like the example below, it gives me an internal server error:

RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !12\.34\.56\.78$ (my ip) 
RewriteRule pageA pageB [R=301]
RewriteRule pageC pageD [R=301]